# Why I get "Error #1069: Property softKeyboardRect not found on flash.display.Stage and there is no default value." when I add a DateField component? 

Tags: apache-flex

I am trying to add a DateField component to my flex application but when I click on it I get this runtime error:

[Fault] exception, information=ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property softKeyboardRect not found on flash.display.Stage and there is no default value.

It works ok if I do in a simple application and I add the DateField on it but it does not work when I add it on another application.

```
<mx:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
       color="#333333"
       creationComplete="init()">

.... action script code.....

<fx:Declarations>
    .............
</fx:Declarations>

 <mx:Panel id="MainPanel" title="MyApp" height="1000" width="1100" layout="horizontal" verticalScrollPolicy="auto" >

    <mx:HBox id="HBoxHeader" >
            <mx:DateField id="StartDate">
    </mx:DateField>

    </mx:HBox>
    <mx:VBox id = "VBoxGroupHeader_LB" height="950" width="250"   verticalScrollPolicy="on" visible="true" horizontalAlign="center">
        <mx:Label id="groupLable_LB" text="GROUPS"  />
        <mx:LinkBar id="linkBarGroup" direction="vertical" horizontalAlign="center" itemClick="getMembers(String(event.label))"/>
    </mx:VBox>

    <mx:VBox id = "VBoxMembersHeader_LB" height="950" width="250" verticalScrollPolicy="on" visible="true" horizontalAlign="center">
        <mx:Label id="memberLabel_LB" text="MEMBERS" />
        <mx:LinkBar id="linkBarMember" direction="vertical" horizontalAlign="center" itemClick="getMemberTypes('stats.' + activeGroup + '.' + String(event.label))"/>
    </mx:VBox>

    <mx:VBox id = "VBoxGraphs" height="950" width="580" verticalScrollPolicy="on" visible="true">
    </mx:VBox>

 </mx:Panel>
```

Any idea of what might cause this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

you are targeting older flash player, if you are using SDK 4.6 you need at least flash player 11.1.